# jQuery Div Links - Does Google Query Data-Href?

Tags: jquery, html

Based upon my research there are two approaches to setting up jQuery div links.

The first approach grabs a link within the div.

```
<div class="divlink"><a class="" href="URL">Link Text</a></div>
```

The second approach grabs the link from a data attribute called "data-href" so there is no need for a link within the div. See below.

```
<div class="divlink" data-href="URL"></div>
```

Is one method better than the other?  My gut tells me that search engines can't follow links in data-href.  Do you think that's true?  Thanks for the help.

Scott

Comment: This question really should be rephased from "which is better" to simply "can search engines follow data-href" links?  "Which is better" is an opinion question.

Comment: Yep, good point, done.

Comment: data-href doesn't get followed by search engines.  I would always use an <a> tag for better SEO and page rankings.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As [this](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-data-href-attributes-links-25926.html) page says, Google does not take `data-href` as links (like `href`).